# Endomorphism example of infinite vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Give an example of infinite vector space $V$ and it's endomorphism $F: V 
\rightarrow V$ that :
a) $F$ is Monomorphism but not Epimorphism
b) $F$ is Epimorphism but not Monomorphism

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V=\Bbb R[x]$ and let

- $F: V\to V,\quad P(x)\mapsto xP(x)$
- $F: V\to V,\quad P(x)\mapsto P'(x)$

can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

The first example that came to mind is very similar to Sami's example in flavor, but visualized in a different way: For any field, let $\mathbb{F}^{\infty}$ denote the vector space of infinite sequences in $\mathbb{F}$, where addition and multiplication are defined termwise. Then, consider the **shift operators** $L, R: \mathbb{F}^{\infty} \to \mathbb{F}^{\infty}$ defined by
\begin{align}
L(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) &:= (x_2, x_3, x_4, \ldots) \\
R(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) &:= (  0, x_1, x_2, \ldots).
\end{align}

> Further hint: You can verify immediately that $L$ and $R$ satisfy some of the criteria using that $L \circ R$ is the identity map.